# Handling a large number of requests that use an ML model

Tags: django, memory-management, machine-learning, word2vec, gensim

I am building a chat-bot where every message a user sends needs to be converted to a vector(for other ML related work). I am using a pre-trained Word2Vec model to do this. The Word2Vec model was created using the Gensim library and is saved to disk as a 600MB file and is being used in a Django/Python web-application.

Every time a new message is received as an API request, a function loads the word2Vec model and uses that object to generate a vector of the message. This needs to happen on a real time basis. I am worried that every time a new message is received, the application loads an instance of the Word2Vec model and this would cause a memory problem if there are too many requests coming at the same time(because there will be multiple instance of the Word2Vec model present in the RAM at that time). How do I handle the memory efficiently such that it does not use too much memory?

Answer (score 0):

Does the "vector" need to be generated and returned to the user immediately? If not, you could consider passing the request to a [celery worker](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html).

You can then choose how many workers you wish to assign to the processing queue, to restrict memory usage to a manageable level.

Comment: yes it needs to be generated immediately i.e. this happens on a real time basis

Comment: If you have a look at [Queueing Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) then you'll see the only way to guarantee that each task is immediately addressed is to ensure that you have more workers available than you'd ever expect expect tasks to arrive. This means enough memory available such that each worker can run the model. If that is too much memory, then unfortunately you'll have to queue the tasks and have celery work through them. You could alert the user of task completion through either email of something like [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).